# How do I add the content of a column based on a condition in other variable

Tags: r

In R, I would like to make a new variable df$TOTAL_VOLUME to add the content together of variable AMOUNT per ID.

So in this case I would like to see that df$TOTAL_VOLUME for A_001 adds up to 4, for B_002 adds up to 1, and for C_003 adds up to 2.5.

| ID | DATE | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A_001 | 2018-11-26 | 0.5 |
| A_001 | 2018-11-26 | 0.5 |
| A_001 | 2020-08-01 | 1.5 |
| A_001 | 2020-08-01 | 1.5 |
| B_002 | 2022-05-23 | 0.5 |
| B_002 | 2022-05-23 | 0.5 |
| C_003 | 2015-03-11 | 1.5 |
| C_003 | 2023-12-06 | 0.5 |
| C_003 | 2023-12-06 | 0.5 |

I don't know how to do this, thank you so much

Comment: And also, how would I do this if I need the DATE to be exactly the same in order to be taken into account when adding column AMOUNT?

Answer (score 0):

Easy with `tidyverse`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- structure(list(ID = c("A_001", "A_001", "A_001", "A_001", "B_002",
                            "B_002", "C_003", "C_003", "C_003"), 
                     DATE = structure(c(17861, 17861, 18475, 18475, 19135, 
                                        19135, 16505, 19697, 19697), 
                                      class = "Date"), 
                     AMOUNT = c(0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 1.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 0.5, 0.5)),
                row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


df %>% 
  mutate(TOTAL_VOLUME = sum(AMOUNT), .by = ID)

# # A tibble: 9 × 4
#   ID    DATE       AMOUNT TOTAL_VOLUME
#   <chr> <date>      <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1 A_001 2018-11-26    0.5          4  
# 2 A_001 2018-11-26    0.5          4  
# 3 A_001 2020-08-01    1.5          4  
# 4 A_001 2020-08-01    1.5          4  
# 5 B_002 2022-05-23    0.5          1  
# 6 B_002 2022-05-23    0.5          1  
# 7 C_003 2015-03-11    1.5          2.5
# 8 C_003 2023-12-06    0.5          2.5
# 9 C_003 2023-12-06    0.5          2.5
```

---

Or in base R:

```r
df$TOTAL_VOLUME <- ave(df$AMOUNT, df$ID, FUN = sum)
df
# # A tibble: 9 × 4
#   ID    DATE       AMOUNT TOTAL_VOLUME
#   <chr> <date>      <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1 A_001 2018-11-26    0.5          4  
# 2 A_001 2018-11-26    0.5          4  
# 3 A_001 2020-08-01    1.5          4  
# 4 A_001 2020-08-01    1.5          4  
# 5 B_002 2022-05-23    0.5          1  
# 6 B_002 2022-05-23    0.5          1  
# 7 C_003 2015-03-11    1.5          2.5
# 8 C_003 2023-12-06    0.5          2.5
# 9 C_003 2023-12-06    0.5          2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for this answer.

It does give me the TOTAL_VOLUME in the tibble but does not write it back into the dataframe. Could you please tell me how to do this?

Also, if want to add the DATE in this condition, besides the ID, can I just add it in the code?

df %>%
mutate(TOTAL_VOLUME = sum(AMOUNT), .by = ID, DATE)

Comment: Welcome to SO Rabbit8. Please consider using comments section instead of answers to reply to answers